# Why a parameter of an Emacs lisp function is not evaluated?

Tags: emacs, elisp, metaprogramming

I want to define a list of accumulators with Emacs Lisp and write the following code, but I got a error saying that `initV` is a void variable. It seems `initV` is not evaluated in the function `define-accum`. Where is I make a mistake? (I just want to know why although I know there is other ways to reach my target.)

```
(defun define-accum (name initV)
  (defalias name (lambda (v) (+ v initV))))

(setq accums '((myadd1 . 1)
               (myadd2 . 2)))

(dolist (a accums)
  (define-accum (car a) (cdr a)))

(message "result = %d" (+ (myadd1 1) (myadd2 1)))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apart from using backquotes, you can [activate lexical binding](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Using-Lexical-Binding.html#Using-Lexical-Binding) (if you're using Emacs 24 or newer).  For example, if I put your code in a `.el` file and put this on the first line:

```
;; -*- lexical-binding: t -*-
```

then I get the output:

```
result = 5
```

This works because the lambda function in `define-accum` will reference the `initV` in the environment where it's being defined (thus picking the variable in the argument list), and create a closure over this variable.  With dynamic binding (the default), the function would look for `initV` in the environment where it's being called.

Answer (score 3):

You need to use backquotes properly.  This would work for you, for instance:

```
(defun define-accum (name initV)
  (defalias name `(lambda (v) (+ v ,initV))))
```

See [here](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Backquote.html) for an explanation

Comment: Thanks. I know the usage of backquotes but I still don't understand why there should be quoting.

Comment: The problem is that `lambda` is self-quoting. Therefore, `initV` stands literally in the alias. It is undefined at the evaluation of the alias.

Answer (score 1):

To add a little to what others have said -

1. If the variable (`initV`) is never actually used **as a variable**, so that in fact its **value** at the time the accumulator is defined is all that is needed, then there is no need for the lexical closure that encapsulates that variable and its value.  In that case, the approach described by @juanleon is sufficient: it uses only the value at definition time - the variable does not exist when the function is invoked (as you discovered).
2. On the other hand, the lexical-closure approach lets the function be byte-compiled.  In the backquote approach, the function is simply represented at runtime by a **list** that represents a lambda form.  If the lambda form represents costly code then it can make sense to use the lexical-closure approach, even though (in this case) the variable is not really needed (as a variable).
3. But you can always explicitly byte-compile the function (e.g. ##NAME## in your `define-accum`.  That will take care of the inefficiency mentioned in #2, above.

Comment: Note that closures don't like "variables" any more than backquoted lambdas.  The only difference is that the byte-compiler will take care of rewriting the code for you if needed (e.g. it will turn `(let ((a 1)) ... (setq a ..) ... a ...)` into `(let ((a (list 1))) ... (setcar a ..) ... (car a) ...)`).